# Rails not resolving from a custom namespace to a root one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I've followed some of the guidelines for Rails but I'm facing the following issue

```
app
 controller
 models
 ..
 api/users
 utils
```

I have this util class

```
#app/utils/my_util.rb
class MyUtil
  self.clean(data)
    ...
  end
end

#app/api/users/profile
class Api::Users::Profile
  def cleanup_name
    ::MyUtil.clean(name)
  end
end
```

When running this in rails, I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant MyUtil
```

I'm pointing to the root namespace, so I'm confused as to why it's throwing the error.

Comment: Is `app/utils` added to the `autoload_paths` in your `application.rb` file?

Comment: I thought since it's under app, it should be autoloaded

Comment: It should be autoloaded. Can you open the rails console and are you able to reference the constant `MyUtil` there?

Comment: It looks like it was not autoloaded. Manually adding the folder in application.rb file did it

Comment: I experimented with this a bit and I had to kill my console, run `spring stop`, and then re-launch the console in order for the app to actually re-boot and automatically update the autoload paths.